# Getting variables from a form which uses a div instead of input

Tags: html, forms, variables, button, post

This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="configuration/raportare/generate_crangasi.php">
<div id="reportrange" name="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar">
</i>&nbsp;<span></span> 
<b class="caret"></b>
</div><br>
<button type="submit">Generează raport</button>
</form>
```

And this is the generate_orhideea.php file:

```
//SOME CODE HERE
require_once "../../configuration/db.php";
$begin = $_POST['reportrange'];
$rows = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM clienti_orhideea WHERE data_inregistrare >= '$begin'");
//SOME CODE HERE
```

I am getting the errors:

> Undefined variable reportrange

How can I fix this?

Comment: Nope. Has to be an input field.

Comment: You are right. I changed the whole code. Thank you!

Comment: You should change your question or add the revised code to an answer :)

Comment: I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code to:

```
<form method="POST" action="configuration/raportare/generate_crangasi.php">
<input type="text" name="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Generează raport">
</form>
```

I wanted to use a `<div>` and a `<button>` for some javascript code, but I adapted it to work with input `type="submit"`. Also I eliminated the

```
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar">
    </i>&nbsp;<span></span> 
    <b class="caret"></b>
```

code which will not work with input anymore. (I adeed this glyphon in css).

Comment: Did you want the PHP to record that glyphicon? There's a way you can do that.

Comment: How can I integrate that glyphicon inside an input?Without css? :D

Comment: Turn the whole thing into a php variable. But may I ask, what is the purpose of having someone submit just an icon in the form?

Comment: The icon was just for pure design.

Comment: So it is not part of the form submission then? It would be possible though, if you turned the class into a string.

Comment: In http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples look at the Predefined Ranges demo input. Inside the input is a nice icon and a small arrow, just for design.